# Converting date and time back to millis

Tags: android, string, date, time, android-graphview

I want to plot a graph using graphView , value vs Time.
I have value as integer but I have strings for date and time. 
So, to plot the graph I should be having both values and (date and time) in integral format. 
So, what should I do to plot the graph . Is there any best method for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Calendar:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int yearX = 1980;
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearX);
    int monthX = 5;
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthX);
    int dayX = 15;
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayX);
    int hourX = 1;
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourX);
    int minX = 25;
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minX);
    int secX = 55;
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, secX);
    int milX = 15;
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, milX);

    long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```